# Backbone, correct way of saving data into a model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have two ways of saving data (into a rest API), it works Ok in both ways but I was wondering which one is the way to go.

**1st way:**

```
// here serializeObject just converts form inputs into a serialized object
var inputs_data = this.ui.form.serializeObject();
// here in 3rd param from extend is the same as this.model.unset('logged');
var data = _.extend(this.model.toJSON(), inputs_data ,{logged: undefined});
// here I save and the data goes Ok!
this.model.save(data);
```

**2nd way:**

```
// here i serialize the object the same as above
var inputs_data = this.ui.form.serializeObject();
// here i exclude 3rd parameter 
var data = _.extend(this.model.toJSON(), inputs_data);
// set data with model.set instead of model.save
this.model.set(data);
// remove unwanted attributes
this.model.unset('logged',{silent:true});
// finnaly just save
this.model.save(data);
```

So far I am using the 1st way, so I do not know if the app goes bigger it will bring any problems because of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go this way. You don't have to pass all attributes to model's `save` method, only the attributes that need to be changed (http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save)

```
var inputs_data = this.ui.form.serializeObject();
// remove unwanted attributes
delete inputs_data.logged;
// finally just save
this.model.save(inputs_data);
```

Comment: By watching the two ways I also got the conlusion that in the 2nd one  it would seem to work fine when updating model data and at the same time saving it, let's say like a live edit mode(sync).

Comment: Use `set` if you need to change model's attributes without syncing it. Then later you can call `save` without parameters to sync it to the server.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you I would use either [Backbone.StickIt](http://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/) to synchronise an existing model with the form or use [Backbone.Syphon](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.syphon/) to do something similar to what you are doing above.